# Clojure elastic search API Elastisch not returning results or documents

Tags: clojure, elasticsearch, elastisch

I am trying out clojure elastic search API [Elastisch](http://clojureelasticsearch.info/articles/getting_started.html).

I was following the demo code given in the documentation
I am getting document/index created output for the following code

```
(defn demo-search-connect []
  (esr/connect! "http://127.0.0.1:9200")
  (let [mapping-types {:person {:properties {:username   {:type "string" :store "yes"}
                                         :first-name {:type "string" :store "yes"}
                                         :last-name  {:type "string"}
                                         :age        {:type "integer"}
                                         :title      {:type "string" :analyzer
                                          "snowball"}
                                         :planet     {:type "string"}
                                         :biography  {:type "string" :analyzer   "snowball" :term_vector "with_positions_offsets"}}}}
    doc {:username "happyjoe" :first-name "Joe" :last-name "Smith" :age 30 :title "Teh Boss" :planet "Earth" :biography "N/A"}]

 (esi/create "myapp2_development" :mappings mapping-types)
;; adds a document to the index, id is automatically generated by ElasticSearch
;= {:ok true, :_index people, :_type person, :_id "2vr8sP-LTRWhSKOxyWOi_Q", :_version 1}
(println (esd/create "myapp2_development" :person doc :settings {"number_of_shards" 1}))
))

;Supposed to return an output for the search query 
(defn demo-search-index [] 
  (esr/connect! "http://127.0.0.1:9200")
  (esd/search "myapp2_development" "person" :query {:term {:last_name "Smith"}})
  )

;Supposed to return the document with the given id
(defn get-document [id]
  (esr/connect! "http://127.0.0.1:9200")
  (esd/get "myapp2_development" "person" id)
  )
```

I am getting the output for the first function as :

```
{:ok true, :_index myapp2_development, :_type :person, :_id GzNdzrqhQECQDlkSbq-GHA, :_version 1}
```

From the output I believe the document is getting indexed properly

The issue is that the second and third functions returns:

```
{:took 153, :timed_out false, :_shards {:total 5, :successful 5, :failed 0}, :hits {:total 0, :max_score nil, :hits []}}
```

and `nil` respectively.

What am I missing here?

P.S : I am new to clojure and elastic search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esd/get` fails because your mapping type is `:person` not `"person"` (keyword vs. string).

Your code `esd/search` has the same problem, but in addition you should change `last_name` to `last-name` and by lower casing `"Smith"` to `"smith"` everything should work.

Comment: Thank you!!! That solves it. Was wondering why demo code in the documentation had the keyword as a string?

Comment: Might be a mistake on their part, or a problem with different versions behaving in a different way (I am using 1.0.2 and I could repeat your problems). They are quite helpful on GitHub and on their mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure-elasticsearch) if you wish to find out more.